# How to create users from array and return their ids in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Service get array of users' names, check every name if user with this name exists(if not then create user) and return ids of users with such names. I don't know how to do it because search and save are async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is for query the collection to get a document based on id .if its found it returns the doc other wise it can inseret the doc for that we used {upsert:true}.this is basic code sample follow mongoose docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id},{upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
    if (err)  {
        console.log('if error occurs'); 
    } else {
        console.log('doc',doc) 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using async library for node js.